# After sleep, Messages doesn't consult Keychain for passwords

Tags: macos, messages, keychain

My MacBook will often sleep while I take a break, and when it wakes up, Messages doesn't consult Keychain for passwords. Instead, I'm prompted for all of my passwords again.

Why is this? Is there something I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Disk Utility to verify volumes and repair permissions on the startup volume, then Keychain Access to verify or repair the keychains
2. run Messages
3. sleep then wake the computer
4. if the problem persists, remove relevant items from keychains then allow Messages to replace the items.

Comment: What's the relationship between system file permissions and the problem?

Comment: Wonder whether something is not permitted to access the item in the keychain.

Comment: Apple just posted an update recently that fixes "issues with Keychain" actually.

Comment: OK – [OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2 Supplemental Update 2.0](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1611) on 2012-11-20 for all Mac systems introduced in 2012, let us know whether it's applicable and whether it resolves the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the update seems to have fixed the problem.